# URL prefix for posts WordPress

Tags: wordpress

So I have website on a WordPress engine. And I want to make posts urls looks like http://website.com/blog/post-name/ or http://website.com/blog/categ-name/post-name/. But everything else will look like http://website.com/page-name/. Just want to add prefix 'blog' to urls for all posts but not pages. My permalink settings is /%postname%/. If i will put /blog/%postname%/ I will have 'blog' prefix in every URL of my site :( 
I can't find solution in WordPress admin backend and I didn't find any acceptable plugin for this. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 20):

1) Add this rewrite at the end of you `function.php`

```
function add_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite )
{
    $new_rules = array(
        'blog/(.+?)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&name='. $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1),
    );

    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'add_rewrite_rules'); 

function change_blog_links($post_link, $id=0){

    $post = get_post($id);

    if( is_object($post) && $post->post_type == 'post'){
        return home_url('/blog/'. $post->post_name.'/');
    }

    return $post_link;
}
add_filter('post_link', 'change_blog_links', 1, 3);
```

2) Go to Settings > Permalinks and click `Save Changes`.

Comment: It seems that you cannot edit the post slug anymore, after using this solution.

Answer (score 6):

Create a category called `blog` and use the permalink structure `/%category%/%postname%/`.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about this way too. But I have a couple of categories, and I don't wanna to have 'blog' in cats list. Sure, I can hide the 'blog' cat with some hacks. But maybe there is more elegant solution.

Comment: hi, did you find the solution for this, I also have the same problem

Answer (score 5):

I did this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'redefine_post', 1 );
function redefine_post() {
    register_post_type( 'post', array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name_admin_bar' => _x( 'Post', 'add new on admin bar' ),
        ),
        'public'  => true,
        '_builtin' => false,
        '_edit_link' => 'post.php?post=%d',
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'map_meta_cap' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'blog' ),
        'query_var' => false,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'post-formats' ),
    ) );
}
```

It involves creating a custom post type (which is slightly annoying), but it overrides and works with post.

I wish there was a better way of doing this!
(Otherwise yes you get /blog/ in front of everything if you just change the permalinks).

Answer (score 5):

Go to Settings > Permalinks, choose "Custom Structure" and rewrite this field to "/blog/%postname%/". Your post will get /blog/ prefix, but your pages doesn't. I've tested it at Wordpress 5.2.2

Comment: Problem with this solution is that it will add `blog` prefix in front of everything. Every CPT.

Comment: @ZdenekHatak if a CPT is registered with the option `'rewrite' => array( 'with_front' => false )` then it should be OK. Docs for `with_front` flag: "(bool) Whether the permastruct should be prepended with WP_Rewrite::$front. Default true.". See: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/

Answer (score 0):

```
function golden_oak_web_design_blog_generate_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) {
  $new_rules = array(
    '(([^/]+/)*blog)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[3]',
    'blog/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&name=$matches[1]',
    'blog/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&attachment=$matches[1]',
    'blog/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/trackback/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&attachment=$matches[1]&tb=1',
    'blog/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
    'blog/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
    'blog/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&attachment=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]',     
    'blog/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/embed/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&attachment=$matches[1]&embed=true',
    'blog/[^/]+/embed/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&attachment=$matches[1]&embed=true',
    'blog/([^/]+)/embed/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&name=$matches[1]&embed=true',
    'blog/[^/]+/([^/]+)/embed/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&attachment=$matches[1]&embed=true',
    'blog/([^/]+)/trackback/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&name=$matches[1]&tb=1',
    'blog/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
    'blog/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
    'blog/page/([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&paged=$matches[1]',
    'blog/[^/]+/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]',
    'blog/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]',
    'blog/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&name=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]',
    'blog/([^/]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&name=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]',
    'blog/[^/]+/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&attachment=$matches[1]',
    'blog/[^/]+/([^/]+)/trackback/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&attachment=$matches[1]&tb=1',
    'blog/[^/]+/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
    'blog/[^/]+/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
    'blog/[^/]+/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&attachment=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]',
  );
  $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'golden_oak_web_design_blog_generate_rewrite_rules' );

function golden_oak_web_design_update_post_link( $post_link, $id = 0 ) {
  $post = get_post( $id );
  if( is_object( $post ) && $post->post_type == 'post' ) {
    return home_url( '/blog/' . $post->post_name );
  }
  return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_link', 'golden_oak_web_design_update_post_link', 1, 3 );
```

Comment: Paste the above code snippet into the functions.php file of your active parent theme or child theme.

Reference Link: https://www.goldenoakwebdesign.com/blog/how-to-force-wordpress-urls-to-use-blog-in-posts-permalink-structure

Comment: Once you pasted the above code. Go to Settings --> Permalinks and click Save Changes.